# Run 'find' using exec.Command

Tags: go

I am trying to run the `find` command using `exec.Command`:

```
cmd := exec.Command("find", "/usr/bin", "-maxdepth", 
        "2", "-iname", "'*go*'", "|", "head", "-10")
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

Unfortunately this fails with the following output:

```
exit status 1
find: paths must precede expression: |
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT:

Even if I try it without piping this still fails:

```
cmd := exec.Command("find", "/usr/bin", "-maxdepth", "2", "-iname", "'*go*'")
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

Output:

```
<nil>
```

Comment: a `|` pipe is a shell construct. You can't use that in a command.

Comment: You have unnecessary single quotes around `*go*`, remove them.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `|` which pipes the output of the previous command into the next. Instead you probably need two commands in Go. Use `string(out)` as input to the second one rather than trying to pipe it and compose the two bash commands into one Go command.

```
// this is pseudo code
cmd2 := exec.Command("head", "args1", string(out))
```

Basically, you have to do the piping yourself and use two separate commands rather than trying to invoke command once with commands that are composed using pipe.